# (sqlite3) how to rtrim '\n' as a raw string?

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7

I have a sqlite table named table1

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table1(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, URL varchar(500), Title varchar(500))")
```

URL has data like this: http://www.site.com/content/\n

I want to strip the last raw string \n, but failed with this method

```
cur.execute("UPDATE Table1 SET URL = rtrim(URL,'\n'), Title = rtrim(Title,'\n')")
```

The result remains the same (ULR: http://www.site.com/content/\n). It seems that '\n' is treated as a newline character instead of raw string, how could I rtrim \n as raw string? (URL ends with \n will be trimmed, while URL ends with n will remain untouched)

Comment: Use `\\n` to escape the backslash, or put an `r` in front of your query string... `cur.execute(r'UPDATE...')` - However, if you're using Python as the main interface to sqlite3 - is there any reason you're putting the database in there with the line ends to start with?

Comment: why not trim the string in python? why do it in sqlite?

Comment: Thanks, I tried both \\n and r methods, however, it seems that URL ends with 'n' is also affected. For example, URL: http://www.site.com/fallen now becomes URL:http://www.site.com/falle, and I can't figure out why

Comment: @michelle26 because `.rtrim` removes characters not substrings.... You  might be able to get away with `replace` instead... (but you should really be looking at how to not have to be doing this operation in the first place...)

Comment: Your SQL UPDATE works fine for me; if you don't see changes in the database then either you have made an incorrect assumption about your data or you didn't commit the transaction.

Comment: @JonClements: SQLite doesn't support C-style escapes in string literals. The literal newline itself works fine, as far as SQLite is concerned (I tested). Something else is wrong.

Comment: What count is returned for `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE URL LIKE '%\n' OR Title LIKE '%\n'")`?

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE Table1 SET URL=rtrim(URL, '\n'), Title=rtrim(Title, '\n')")
```

works just fine for SQLite, it does remove newlines from the end of a string. If this doesn't work for you, your values *do not have newlines at the end*, or you didn't commit your transaction.

Alternatives that give the same results:

- You could pass in the newlines as parameters:

  ```
  cur.execute('UPDATE Table1 SET URL=rtrim(URL, ?), Title=rtrim(Title, ?)', ('\n', '\n'))
  ```
- Use `X'...'` to specify a BLOB literal, using hexadecimal notation:

  ```
  cur.execute("UPDATE Table1 SET URL=rtrim(URL, X'0A'), Title=rtrim(Title, X'0A')")
  ```